# Quick Regex php - getting ID from a string

Tags: php, regex

As anyone who's seen my posts will know, I'm a regex pleb. Anyone can tell me how to get the ID from this file name, would be very grateful?

```
/data/64786/sasf.zip
```

I need the **64786** bit from this line, always follows **/data/** - anyone able to help quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~/data/(\d+)/~
```

This will match a sequence of decimals (0-9) immediately following the string `/data/`. Match is in group `1`.

If the string can also look like `/data/64786` (i.e., nothing after the number), use `~/data/(\d+)~` instead. Actually, you can use this either way since `\d+` will be greedy per default and thus match as many decimals as possible. ([Tested at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/bT1ttatADj).)

Comment: Though all others seem to work this was the best answer for the job. Thanks!

Comment: @WiseDonkey You're welcome. When posting regexp questions you should take extra care to state *both* what's certain ("always follows /data/") *and* what varies (e.g., will there always be a slash after the ID?). This will reduce the amount of assumptions (and - not least - the following questioning of those) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a number. Use the `\d+` placeholder for **d**ecimals:

```
preg_match("#(\d+)#", $str, $matches);
$id = $matches[1];
```

If the id always occurs at the same place, then you can add the slashes `#/(\d+)/#` for reliability. Most text strings can be used as-is in regular expressions as anchors.

[reference, tools] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the ID using the following code:

```
$filename = '/data/64786/sasf.zip';
$prefix = '/data/';
$prefix_pos = strpos($filename, $prefix);

if($prefix_pos !== false)
{
    $prefix_pos_end = $prefix_pos + strlen($prefix);
    $slash_pos   = strpos($filename, '/', $prefix_pos_end);
    $id          = substr($filename, $prefix_pos_end, $slash_pos - $prefix_pos_end);
}
else    $id         = false;
```

Comment: This might be faster than a regular expressionbut it will also not check the length of the ID (might be 5 or 500000 as well) and it won't check the beginning being "data".

Comment: @Mario: That is not correct. I am searching the ID using substring and beginning from position 6 (after '/data/'). Also, I am searching the slash after the ID. So if doesn't really matter if the number is 50 or 500000.

Comment: Yes, interpreted that part in the wrong way, however there's no guarantee it's indeed "/data/" in front of the number and the trailing slash can't be ommited.

Comment: @Mario At least there's no guarantee (from what can be read in the question) that the `/data/` (six chars) is *at the beginning* of the string/line.

Comment: @Mario: That is true, but does your answer guarantee it is indeed "/data/"?

Comment: I have updated my code. It does now search the prefix e.g. `/data/` and returns the number after it (before the slash).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try: [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)([dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)("/data/64786/sasf.zip"))

Comment: This will break in case someone adds an additional "/" for whatever reason.