# PHP URL Regex and Parameter

Tags: php, regex

I want to match a URL on my 404 page and based on that I want to redirect user to particular location.

The URL is `http://domain.com/there/12345`

```
// example: /there/12345
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (preg_match('', $request)) {

}
```

What **REGEX** I should put to get this? And once the test is successful, how can I retrieve this ID (**12345**) right after constant **there**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick Regex php - getting ID from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378843/quick-regex-php-getting-id-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regexp you want to use is:

```
$str=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];   
$regex = '/\/there\/(\d+)/';
$matches=array();
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches)
```

This gives

```
array
  0 => string '/there/12345' (length=12)
  1 => string '12345' (length=5)
```

Notice the parantheses around `\d+` capture anything that `\d+` matches (i.e. continuous string of digits 0-9)

If you want to have a hexadecimal id (like 12ABF) then you should change the `\d+` to `[a-zA-Z\d]+`

Comment: The good thing with this solution is you put [a-zA-Z\d]+ and saved me going into comment cycle!

Comment: `[a-fA-F\d]+` would be better for validation hexadecimal

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

```
$path = "http://domain.com/there/12345";
$filename = basename($path);  
echo $filename; // Sholud be 12345
```

Comment: That's neat, I must try and remember this one.

Comment: This does nothing to ensure matching of the `/there/` string component.  Still, `basename` is highly convenient if getting `12345` is the only goal for this question.

Comment: @macek YES, You are right. This function will returns trailing name component of path.

Answer (score 1):

This will work :)

```
if(preg_match('#^/there/(\d+)$#', $request, $matches)){
  echo "the id is {$matches[1]}";
}
else {
  echo "no match!";
}
```

[See it work here](http://ideone.com/LpBvR)

Explanation

```
#          delimiter
^          beginning of string
/there/    string literal '/there/'
(          begin capture group 1
  \d+      one or more [0-9]
)          end capture group 1
$          end of string
#          delimiter
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need:

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$match = array();
if (preg_match('@^/there/(\d+)$@', $request, $match)) {
    $id = $match[1];
    // Do your processing here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you tend to forget the \d syntax, and want to avoid the @ symbol or / as a delimiter:

```
$request = '/there/12345';

if (preg_match('#/there/([0-9]+)#', $request, $match)) {
    $id = $match[1];
    echo "ID: $id";
}
```