# Getting value from database to a folder name PHP&MYSQL

Tags: php, get

I am having a problem with a PHP script, so the link is like this: `page.php?id=1412`.

But I don't want to get the data using `$_GET['id']`; is there a way for the program to recognize the URL like this `localhost/1412`, and then try to find the `1412` in the `id` field in database?

If possible how can I avoid the `Not Found page ?` since the folder 1412 does not exist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all of this kind of matching you need to use either .htaccess files for apache, or similar functionality implemented in the configuration files of nginx/lighthttpd and so on. Basicly, when a request like x/1412 will come, you can match it before being dispatched to the php engine and transform it internally into x?id=1412 . Other solution involves redirecting all requests to a front controller (a script that is serving as a single entry point into the application) and let a url matcher match the route to execute. The latter is implemented in about every big/small php framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could regex the current uri ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']). See for creating regex: [PHP URL Regex and Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375032/php-url-regex-and-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

**.htaccess file is a solution**, you can access this type of url and can send the value to php files using **.htaccess** file refer this nice article for doing this

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/